# cnosdb both datanodes are cold ,and then the Prompt message wrong

Tags: database, cnosdb

version: cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 842fc0e
Both nodes are cold nodes, and the error message returned shows "Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 1""

```
db002 ❯ create database db003 with  cooling_duration '1m' vnode_duration '1m';
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030053","error_message":"Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 1"}
db002 ❯ show datanodes;
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| NODE_ID | HOST      | ATTRIBUTE | STATUS  | DISK_FREE | DISK_TOTAL | LOCATION   | LAST_UPDATED_TIME   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1001    | localhost | COLD      | HEALTHY | 65.16 GB  | 243.11 GB  | /dc1/rack1 | 2023-12-19 09:57:16 |
| 2001    | localhost | COLD      | HEALTHY | 65.16 GB  | 243.11 GB  | /dc1/rack2 | 2023-12-19 09:57:17 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
Query took 0.002 seconds.
```

the right truth is "Both nodes are cold nodes, and the error message returned shows "Valid node is not enough, need: 1, but found: 0""
"